# Non-interactive ploting with matplotlib on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am using [scipy-cluster](http://code.google.com/p/scipy-cluster/) in my application. It provides a function to plot a dendrogram of the hierarchical cluster tree. Looking at the source I find that it eventually plots the dendrogram by calling `draw_if_interactive`. As one would expect, this works fine in an interactive session, but when I run the script non-interactively, a window pops up and immediately vanishes again (I have configured matplotlib to use the [`macosx`-backend](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#backends)). I need a way to either make my application wait until the user closes the window showing the plot, or to make it render directly into a file (which actually I would prefer). Again, the problem is, that I cannot modify the code that generates the plot, so the solution will probably involve some configuration settings for matplotlib or something like that.

**EDIT**: I added my current workaround as an answer, so others may use it. Since it is very ugly, I will leave this question open hoping for someone to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I came up with for now:

```
class myplot(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename

    def resetFileName(self, fileName):
        self._filename = fileName

    def __call__(self):
        matplotlib.pylab.savefig(self._filename)

plotfunction = myplot("foo.png")
matplotlib.pylab.draw_if_interactive = plotfunction
```

This must be executed after the `hcluster`-module is imported. This is ugly in many ways, but at least (thanks to the dynamic nature of Python) I do not have to modify the source-code. It let's me set the filename for each plot, and that is just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The macosx backend doesn't support non-interactive mode properly (ie setting interactive off has no effect). You might prefer to use the AGG [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for this --

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')
```